# JMeter: Fields' Values Being Merged

Tags: api, jmeter

[REVISED ORIG POST FOR EASIER REFERENCE]

Running JMeter 2.13 r1665067, I'm performing API testing doing basic CRUD functions using HTTP Requests from JMeter to a database where the 'id' field value is sporadically being "merged" with the hard-coded 'baseUnitValue' field value resulting in a failure and a stack trace message of "*Obj is not found*".

CREATE New Record

```
HTTP POST
    "id": 0,
    "schedulePeriodId": 1259810849,
    "amount": null,
    "baseUnitValue": 10.50,
    "procValue": "G0040",

RESPONSE
    "id": 1259811045,
    "schedulePeriodId": 1259810849,
    "amount": null,
    "baseUnitValue": 10.50,
    "procValue": "G0040"

RegEx Extractor
    Apply to: Main Sample only
    Field to check: Body
    Ref Name: baseUnitId
    Reg Exp: \"id":(.+?)\,
    Template: $1$
    Match No: 1
    Default: None
```

UPDATE (original)

```
HTTP POST
    ${__BeanShell(return vars.get("foobar").replaceAll(vars.get("baseUnitFieldValue")\,"11.50");,)}

    Where it's using/interpreting foobar to contain:
        "id": 12599511.507,
        "periodId": 1259810849,
        "amount": null,
        "baseUnitValue": 11.50,
        "procValue": "G0040"

RESPONSE
    Object with id 12599511 not found...
```

After a number of runs and investigations, a pattern emerged:

- if 'id' = xxxxxx**1045** and baseUnitValue = 10.5, 
  when the UPDATE occurs with a hard-coded 'baseUnitValue' of 11.50, the 'id' value is changed to xxxxxx**11.50**

Basically, every 1000 records would fail when the 'id' would end in xxxxxx1045. I would "appear" the last digits of the 'id' value was being evaluated each time, and when it would end in 1045, it was rounded to 10.50.

---

Thanks to the assistance from @kiril-s and @dmitri-t, the following solution has been created.

First, I added 2 new User Defined Variables

- RND1 4.9999 (*min value*)
- RND2 15.9999 (*max value*)

CREATE (added BeanShell PreProcessor)

```
HTTP POST
    "id": 0,
    "schedulePeriodId": 1259810849,
    "amount": null,
    "baseUnitValue": ${RND},
    "procValue": "G0040",

BeanShell PreProcessor
    Parameters: ${RND1}, ${RND2}
    Script:
    import java.util.*;

    String [] params = Parameters.split(",");

    double rangeMin = Double.valueOf(params[0]);
    double rangeMax = Double.valueOf(params[1]);
    Random r = new Random();
    double randomValue = rangeMin + (rangeMax - rangeMin) * r.nextDouble();
    vars.put("RND",randomValue.toString());
    //System.out.println(randomValue);
```

There is also a REGEX to parameterize the "id" field value assigned by the database. This permits proper READ and DELETE functions by appending the associated URL with the parameter.

When performing the READ HTTP Request, added a BeanShell PostProcessor to the existing 2 REGEX.
    REGEX 1
        Ref Name: foobar
        Reg Exp: (?s)(^.*)

```
REGEX 2
    Ref Name: origFieldValue
    Reg Exp: \,"baseUnitValue":(.+?)\,

BeanShell PostProcessor
    Reset Interpreter: False
    Parameters: ${RND1}, ${RND2}
    Script:
        import java.util.*;

        String [] params = Parameters.split(",");

        double rangeMin = Double.valueOf(params[0]);
        double rangeMax = Double.valueOf(params[1]);
        Random r = new Random();
        double randomValue = rangeMin + (rangeMax - rangeMin) * r.nextDouble(); 

        vars.put("newFieldValue",randomValue.toString());
        //System.out.println(randomValue);
```

This permits the passing of a different value (newFieldValue) to the 'baseUnitFieldValue' without hard-coding.

UPDATE (added JSR223 PreProcessor)

```
HTTP POST
    ${baseUnitValueBody}

JSR223 PreProcessor
    Language: groovy
    Parameters: "newFieldValue"
    Script:
    import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase;
    import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.util.HTTPArgument;

    vars.put("foobar", vars.get("foobar").replace(vars.get("baseUnitFieldValue"),vars.get("newFieldValue")));
```

*Also notice the change from* `replaceAll` *to* `replace`.

Now, the 'baseUnitValue' is always unique and the 'id' field is not being evaluated and transformed every 1000 records. I've run using 500 thread users @ 1 loop and 1000 users @ 3 loops. The original issue no longer occurs. Thanks again to @dmitri-t and @kiril-s.

Additional feedback welcome.

Comment: I didn't check your exact example, but remember that `replaceAll` uses **regex**, so dot in the number will be interpreted as "any character". You need to escape it (with 2 backslashes, i.e. `\\.`) if you want an exact match. So basically you should first do `vars.get("baseUnitFieldValue").replace(".", "\\.")` and then pass it to replaceAll

Comment: Kiril, thanks. I tried your suggestion and the Update failed to properly read the value. So I tried a bunch of variations on your suggestion, but all failed.    `${__BeanShell(return vars.get("baseUnitValueBody").replaceAll(vars.get("baseUnitFieldValue")\,"11\\.50");,)}` 
    `${__BeanShell(return vars.get("baseUnitValueBody").replaceAll(vars.get("baseUnitFieldValue")\,"11\.50");,)}`
    `${__BeanShell(return vars.get("baseUnitValueBody").replaceAll(vars.get("baseUnitFieldValue"),"11\\.50");,)}`

Comment: yea, I forgot that if you use `\,` you cannot use backslash for anything else in the inline script. So you can either move your script to BeanShell Pre- or Post-processor, or how about using replace? Is there ever a case when there are more than one values you want to replace? I.e.: `${__BeanShell(return vars.get("foobar").replace(vars.get("baseUnitFieldValue")\,"11.50");)}`

Comment: Kiril, take a look at my update above to see what I ended up doing with a JSR223 PreProcessor. Any insight is much appreciated! :)

Comment: David, groovy is still java, so replaceAll still works the same way: `1259971045` matches regex 10.5 (10, any digit, which happens to be 4, then 5). Similar in other cases. So all my other comments still stand: you can either replace it with `replace` (`vars.put("foobar", vars.get("foobar").replacel(vars.get("baseUnitFieldValue"),"11.50"));`) or escape the dot with backslash (now that you are in pre-processor you should be able to do `replace(".", "\\.")`

Comment: Thanks for your help! I think between your insightful answer, the other answer, and a lot of surfing the boards, I believe I've resolved it. I'm going to clean-up  my original question (for future reference by others) followed by what I've done to eliminate the hard-coding issue.

Answer (score 0):

This may happen due to Beanshell interpreter performance problem. It is [recommended](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) to use JSR223 Test Elements and [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) language for scripting when it comes to high loads.

First of all download [groovy-all.jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all), drop it to Jmeter's "lib" folder and restart JMeter to pick the jar up.

Redesign your UPDATE record as follows:

- [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request)

  - [JSR223 PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor)

In JSR223 PostProcessor:

1. Use "groovy" as a language
2. Put something unique into "Compilation cache key" input
3. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   vars.put("foobar", vars.get("foobar").replaceAll(vars.get("baseUnitFieldValue"),"11.50"));
   ```

It should fix your problem. See [Beanshell vs JSR223 vs Java JMeter Scripting: The Performance-Off You've Been Waiting For!](https://blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-java-jmeter-scripting-its-performance) for detailed explanations, instructions on installing groovy engine support and scripting best practices.

Comment: Thanks for the assist. Based on the information you provided, I added a JSR223 Pre-Processor to the HTTP Request. 
    Compilation cache = newFooBar 
`import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase;` (_is this really needed?_) 
`import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.util.HTTPArgument;` (_is this really needed?_) 
`vars.put("baseUnitValueBody", vars.get("baseUnitValueBody").replaceAll(vars.get("baseUnitFieldValue"),"11.50"));` 
In HTTP Request, I replaced the old beanshell statement with just `${foobar}`. (_Took me a while to figure this out_)  Now it seems to work correctly.

Comment: DARN! **Even with the JSR233 PreProcessor**, I just got the original issue `{"id":12599511.50...}` again after I increased the # of Threads and Ramp Up Period.   I configured _Thread #_ = 100, _Ramp Up Period_ = 2000, and _Loop Count_ = 10. Could it be a memory config. issue? (using default) not enough Ramp Up time? Constant Throughput Timer? (set at 900.0)

Comment: Don't use variables like `${foobar}` in groovy, it makes compilation feature senseless